# iOS Tags Cleanup

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, tags, retag-request, synonym-request

Right now the iOS tags are a little messy. Here are my points on what should be done:

- Merge [iphone-sdk-6.0](/questions/tagged/iphone-sdk-6.0) into [ios6](/questions/tagged/ios6). Technically you could say that if you are developing a website and it doesn't work with iOS 6 you could tag it with that but the thing is, **everybody who uses the iOS SDK tags it with [ios](/questions/tagged/ios)**. And the further back my point, **[iphone-sdk](/questions/tagged/iphone-sdk) already redirects to [iphone](/questions/tagged/iphone)**. And additionally, **ipad-sdk tags do not exist**.
- Same as above but with [iphone-sdk-5.0](/questions/tagged/iphone-sdk-5.0), [iphone-sdk-4.0](/questions/tagged/iphone-sdk-4.0) and any other minor versions too. Make sure it maps to the right iOS version though. Anything below 4.0 can probably stay as that was pre-rename.
- Make [ios-sdk](/questions/tagged/ios-sdk) a synonym to [ios](/questions/tagged/ios) instead of [iphone](/questions/tagged/iphone). Why does it redirect to iPhone? It the the **iOS** SDK.

And here's a point of discussion. [ios4.1](/questions/tagged/ios4.1) redirects to [ios4](/questions/tagged/ios4). Should [ios5.1](/questions/tagged/ios5.1) redirect to [ios5](/questions/tagged/ios5) or should the [ios4.1](/questions/tagged/ios4.1) synonym be broken? I will update this post with a more detailed list of tags when I know what one people are in favour of.

**EDIT - other iphone-sdk-X.X tags**
*(the following iOS tags currently redirect to [ios4](/questions/tagged/ios4) but such redirect may be broken in the future - see the discussion point)*
[iphone-sdk-4.0.1](/questions/tagged/iphone-sdk-4.0.1) -> [ios4.0.1](/questions/tagged/ios4.0.1)
[iphone-sdk-4.1](/questions/tagged/iphone-sdk-4.1) -> [ios4.1](/questions/tagged/ios4.1)
[iphone-sdk-4.3](/questions/tagged/iphone-sdk-4.3) -> [ios4.3](/questions/tagged/ios4.3)
And an ios-sdk-tag:
[ios-sdk-4.3](/questions/tagged/ios-sdk-4.3) -> [ios4.3](/questions/tagged/ios4.3)

Comment: Interesting points. I'm not sure I agree with all of them, but they are definitely worth discussing.

Comment: [tag:ios-sdk] is a synonym of [tag:iphone] for historical reasons. In the beginning, there was only iPhone. There was no iPad, and there was no iOS. In the *very* beginning, the OS didn't even have a public name. People called it "iPhone OS". It was only much later, after the release of additional devices that the OS took on the name iOS. That also explains why [tag:iphone] is the predominant tag, instead of [tag:ios]. It's really too late to fix now.

Comment: What about cocoa-touch ?

Comment: I normally retag any non hardware iPhone/iPad/iPod questions with iOS whenever I see one. But I believe the amount of questions are too large to do anything now.

Comment: @CodyGray Why is it too late to fix that now? All we have to do is reverse the synonyms -- and in fact it sounds to me like that's what should happen here.

Comment: @Caleb By "too late to fix now", I meant that it's too late to fix [tag:iphone] being the dominant tag, as opposed to [tag:ios]. A synonym won't do between [tag:iphone] and [tag:ios] because you need to be able to tag iPhone-specific issues.

Comment: @CodyGray - You make a good point about historical origins, and why one has more questions than the other, but [ios] has overtaken [iphone] in terms of question-asking activity: http://hewgill.com/~greg/stackoverflow/stack_overflow/tags/#!ios+iphone , so I believe that it could be time to switch over the [ios-sdk] synonym. [iphone] and [ios] need to stand apart, but I think we should be directing people to [ios] in terms of more device-independent development questions.

Comment: @Brad Interesting, I wasn't aware of the changing trends. (And what a cool tool!) I agree it would be ideal if we could switch over to [ios] for device-independent questions, I just didn't think it was a realistic goal.

Comment: Do we really need [tag:ios4.0.1]? Can't we just have _one_ for each major version?

Comment: @ColeJohnson That's what I suggested. See the comments in Brad's answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

OK, I started on some of these. The following are the new synonyms I've set up so far:

- [ios-sdk](/questions/tagged/ios-sdk) -> [ios](/questions/tagged/ios) (this did seem to make more sense pointing in this direction)
- [iphone-sdk-6.0](/questions/tagged/iphone-sdk-6.0) -> [ios6](/questions/tagged/ios6)
- [iphone-sdk-5.0](/questions/tagged/iphone-sdk-5.0) -> [ios5](/questions/tagged/ios5)
- [iphone-sdk-4](/questions/tagged/iphone-sdk-4) -> [ios4](/questions/tagged/ios4)
- [iphone-sdk-4.0](/questions/tagged/iphone-sdk-4.0) -> [ios4](/questions/tagged/ios4)

We can add others as we find them.

Looking at these version-specific tags, there are a lot of questions tagged only with a particular version, and not with the broader [ios] or [iphone] tags. These questions are not getting the right kind of visibility they need, but I don't feel right pointing all version-specific tags into the one broader [ios] tag. Not sure how best to clean this up.

Comment: Cheers! What about other iphone-sdk tags like [iphone-sdk-4.1]?

Comment: @BoA - Make a list of the ones you think need to be pointed somewhere, along with the target, and drop me a comment here. I'll look at them and set up synonyms as necessary.

Comment: Will do! And about the version specific iOS tags, [ios4.1] redirects to [ios4] but [ios5.1] does NOT redirect to [ios5]. Shouldn't it all follow the same guideline rather than having some redirect and some not? Which one should it all be?

Comment: Added a small list of the remaining iphone-sdk tags to the post.

Comment: A couple I noticed: [tag:ios-sdk-4.3], [tag:iphone-sdk-3.0] (duplicated for 4.0.1, 3.1, 3.1.2, 3.1.3, 3.2, 2, 2.2.1), etc.

Comment: @BoA - For the .x point versions (5.1, 4.1, etc.), are any of the questions in those specific to something in that point version, or could they just as easily apply to the broader main version? If none of them have anything specific to the point version, I could see directing all of those at the main version tag.

Comment: @Emrakul Should pre-4.0 be redirected since that was before iOS was renamed from iPhone OS?

Comment: @BradLarson I suppose a couple of features do get added that developers use. X.Y.Z versions are less likely as only the runtime changes in those. So I think the [ios4.1] and [ios4.3] synonym on [ios4] should be removed but [ios4.0.1] can stay.

Comment: I think it is best to add iOS tag to all questions which has iosX.Y and iphone-sdkX.Y. No one search with specific version number in tags